# C free() routine and incremented array pointers

Tags: c, memory, pointers, free

Will the `free()` routine work if I dynamically allocate an array and then pass, not the initial pointer, but a pointer to the middle of the array?  Example:

```
int* array = malloc(10 * sizeof *array);
if(array) {

  array += 5; // adjusting the indicies

  free(array);
}
```

Or do I need to set the pointer back to the start of the array before calling `free()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Absolutely not. The value passed to `free()` must be exactly the same value returned by `malloc()`. In fact, to ensure this is the case, I would recommend you use a copy of the pointer if you need a pointer you can increment or otherwise modify.

Comment: Does this mean that in order to avoid memory leak, one must copy the pointer to increment, and then pass the copy to free OR is the increment of the pointer freeing memory in any way, so there is no need of calling free?

Comment: Incrementing the pointer does not free the memory. Calling `free()` is the *only* way to free the memory. If you are going to modify the pointer in any way, you cannot pass the modified pointer to `free()`. *The pointer value you pass to `free()` must be the original value returned from `malloc()`.* Passing any other value will crash your program.

Comment: Also note that copying the pointer does not affect the allocated memory. Copying the pointer is recommended only so that you can modify the copy and still have the original value to pass to `free()`.

Answer (score 5):

### No

(And "Yes", you do need to "set it back".)

The API requires that you only pass to `free()` exactly what you got from `malloc`()<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1. Or a null pointer.</sup>